# Translating SQL query into Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hello @all I have a Problem with my "SQL-Rails-Translation".

`DELETE FROM bookings WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM bookings GROUP BY personal_id, wbs, date, hours, cost_center)`

`Booking.delete_all.where('id NOT IN (?)', Booking.select('MIN(id)').group(:personal_id, :wbs, :date, :hours, :cost_center).map(&:id))`

My SQL query works like the way I want it but I don't know the right "translation" into rails because with the second code above my whole bookings table gets deleted.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

I've the right "translation" for my SQL query.

`Booking.delete_all(['id NOT IN (?)', Booking.group(:personal_id, :wbs, :date, :hours, :cost_center).pluck('MIN(id)')])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've the right "translation" for my SQL query.

```
Booking.delete_all(['id NOT IN (?)', Booking.group(:personal_id, :wbs, :date, :hours, :cost_center).pluck('MIN(id)')])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Booking.delete_all('id NOT IN (?)', Booking.select('MIN(id)').group(:personal_id, :wbs, :date, :hours, :cost_center).pluck(:id))
```

you can give `delete_all` some conditions [more info about delete_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class)

and i replaced map with pluck. because you just need the id, and not the complete objects

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried it but it doesn't work. I've got the following Error-Message:

`PG::GroupingError: FEHLER: Spalte „bookings.id“ muss in der GROUP-BY-Klausel erscheinen oder in einer Aggregatfunktion verwendet werden LINE 1: SELECT "bookings"."id" FROM "bookings" GROUP BY "bookings"."... ^ : SELECT "bookings"."id" FROM "bookings" GROUP BY "bookings"."personal_id", "bookings"."wbs", "bookings"."date", "bookings"."hours", "bookings"."cost_center"`